# How to store custom attribute after place order?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, custom-attributes

I am trying to store customer's reward point into `sales_order` table using event-observer.

here is my events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="save_reward_pont" instance="SimpleMagento\RewardPoint\Observer\SaveRewardPoint" />
</event>
```

and my observer: SaveRewardPoint.php

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
     $order=$observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
     $order->setData('reward_point',0);
}
```

I created `reward_point` column into `sales_order` table, but when the event trigged its throwing

`Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setData() on array`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this below code in your observer file code and check it :

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
     $order=$observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     $order->setData('reward_point',0);
     $order->save();
     return $this;
}
```